# WMQ copy messages between queue managers

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have a queue Q1 on queue manager QMA and an app A reading the data from Q1. The data from Q1 needs to be replicated to another queue Q2 on queue manager QMB with app A still reading from Q1 and Q2 also getting the message. 
I make Q1 an alias queue which posts its data on a topic (TopicA) to which Q2 has subscribed via a remote queue. Q2 is able to get the data.
The problem is app A which was reading from Q1 is not able to get the data. Can this be re-modelled so that both app A and Q2 gets the data?

Comment: Do you have authority to change the putting application code to make it send the message to other queue?

Comment: Yes.. its a configuration

Answer (score 0):

Create another durable subscription for `TopicA` with destination as `Q3` and change your application get messages from queue `Q3` instead of `Q1`. When an application puts message to `Q1` (basically to alias topic `TopicA`) that message gets routed to both `Q2` on `QMB` and `Q3` on `QMA`.

Comment: My current setup restricts me from reading from some other queue other than Q1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the queue for your putting application, then follow below steps:

> 1. Make Q1 as local queue instead of alias queue.
> 2. Create another alias queue, say "Publisher", with Base object as topic and give your topic in destination as you did before.
> 3. Create Subscriptions for queue Q1, for your topic.
> 4. Point your putting application to put messages in the "Publisher" queue instead of Q1.